# Multi-Threading, Multi-Tasking and Multi-Processing

Tags: processing, computer-science

What are differences between

- Multi-Threading
- Multi-Tasking
- Multi-Processing

, And which one has most relation to parallel computing?

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Answer (score 1):

- Threads are within a single application.
- Tasks are separate applications
- Processors are separate CPU chips or separate CPUs on one die.

I don't think you can pick any as being closest to parallel computing without further context.